# "Exception during Alias refresh" while upgrade to Orchard 1.10.2

Tags: c#, orchardcms

Im trying to upgrade from Orchard 1.9.2 to 1.10.2.

I am getting the following excepton in my logs

> 2018-12-07 23:55:27,366 [29]
>   Orchard.Alias.Implementation.Updater.AliasHolderUpdater - (null) -
>   Exception during Alias refresh [http://localhost:30321/]
>   NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not execute query [
>   select aliasrecor0_.Id as Id19_, aliasrecor0_.Path as Path19_,
>   aliasrecor0_.RouteValues as RouteVal3_19_, aliasrecor0_.Source as
>   Source19_, aliasrecor0_.IsManaged as IsManaged19_,
>   aliasrecor0_.Action_id as Action6_19_ from Orchard_Alias_AliasRecord
>   aliasrecor0_ where aliasrecor0_.Id>@p0 order by aliasrecor0_.Id asc ] 
>   Name:p1 - Value:0 [SQL: select aliasrecor0_.Id as Id19_,
>   aliasrecor0_.Path as Path19_, aliasrecor0_.RouteValues as
>   RouteVal3_19_, aliasrecor0_.Source as Source19_,
>   aliasrecor0_.IsManaged as IsManaged19_, aliasrecor0_.Action_id as
>   Action6_19_ from Orchard_Alias_AliasRecord aliasrecor0_ where
>   aliasrecor0_.Id>@p0 order by aliasrecor0_.Id asc] --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'IsManaged'.
>   Statement(s) could not be prepared.
>   ...
>   ...
>   at Orchard.Alias.Implementation.Updater.AliasHolderUpdater.Refresh()

It seems like the migrations are not running seeing as i've checked the `Orchard_Framework_DataMigrationRecord`-table and `Orchard.Alias.Migrations` is at version `1`

`IsManaged` should be added at `UpdateFrom1` in Migrations.cs for the Orchard.Alias Module

```
public int UpdateFrom1() {
    SchemaBuilder.AlterTable("AliasRecord",
            table => table
                .AddColumn<bool>("IsManaged", column => column.WithDefault(false))
        );
    return 2;
}
```

The culprit line seems to be this one in DefaultOrchardShell.cs

```
allRoutes.AddRange(_routeProviders.SelectMany(provider => provider.GetRoutes()));
```

It seems that the migrations never get a chance to run before this exception.

What should i do?
I could add IsManaged manually and hope this is the only issue, but that seems a bit hackish.

Comment: It's unclear to me why `IsManaged` would be an invalid name, but you can certainly hack it by adding the column, then advancing the migration number to 2. The effect will be exactly the same as running the migration. Backup before you try, of course.